# Filter_horizontal not save django admin 4x

Tags: python, django-admin

I'm starting a project in django 4.1. and I run into this problem:
many to many relationship: I have a field of this type that is required, and everything is fine, but when I use the filter_horizontal it does not let me insert the chosen value, it tells me that it is required, however I am selecting values

```
Admin.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CatalejoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    filter_horizontal = ('tematicas',)

admin.site.register(Catalejo, CatalejoAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tematicas)

Model:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Tematicas(models.Model):
    tematica = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True , default=User, editable=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["tematica"]
        verbose_name_plural = "Temática"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tematica

class Catalejo(models.Model):
    fecha =  models.DateField()
    titulo =  models.CharField(max_length=500)  
    tematicas = models.ManyToManyField(Tematicas, related_name='Temáticas') 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True , default=User, editable=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    fichero = models.FileField(upload_to='gestores/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["fecha"]
        verbose_name_plural = "Catalejo"

    def Tematicas(self):
        return ",\n".join([p.tematica for p in self.tematicas.all()])

    def dehydrate_full_title(self, Tematicas):
        return '%s by %s' % (Tematicas.tematica)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9WmE.png)